# xo lint error: `document` is not defined

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've been a long time user of [Standard](http://standardjs.com), and now that I'm working on a new project, I've been asked to start writing semicolons.

I'm trying to use both xo, Babel and React, but I keep getting an error when I try to lint my code:
`document is not defined.  no-undef`

I've tried adding an `env` option to the `xo` field in my package.json file, but no success.

My `xo` config:

```
"xo": {
  "esnext": true,
  "extends": "xo-react",
  "space": true,
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-space-before-closing": 0
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is cumbersome to specify linting options such as `/** global document **/` and edit a configuration file every time you use a global.

This error can be suppressed by using `--env=browser` option:

```
xo --env=browser [<file|glob> ...]
```

**Note:** Same problem comes with Node.js, where the linter will complain that `require` and friends are not defined. The switch has to change to `--env=node` in that case.

However, XO defaults the `env` to `node`, therefore this will not be a problem in most cases. You will need multiple environments if your project contains both client and server files. in that case, `--env` switch can be set multiple times:

```
xo --env=browser --env=node [<file|glob> ...]
```

Comment: Can be also specified in `package.json`: 
`"xo": {
    "envs": ["browser"]
  },`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define globals in ESLint. There are two ways to accomplish this, firstly as a comment in your code:

`/* global document */`

Or you can configure in configuration file like so:

`{
    "globals": {
        "var1": true,
        "var2": false
    }
}`

See the [ESLint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) for more